# Wordpress Header and footer in JS/CSS

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a free theme in which I have to use a custom landing page which has custom HTML, JS and CSS.

How can I make it in that page it has a slider and the content related to the website?

How to use header and footer of the wordpress theme with custom HTML js and css?

Answer (score 0):

**Follow The Steps For Create A Custom Landing Page**

9 Easy Steps for Coding a Custom WordPress Landing Page

```
Step 1: Build a child theme. To create a custom WordPress landing page, you must first create a child theme. ...
Step 2: Create a style.css file. ...
Step 3: Create a functions.php file. ...
Step 4: Install and activate. ...
Step 5: Create a custom page. ...
Step 6: Add images. ...
Step 7: Add a custom header. ...
Step 8: Display your content.
Step 9: Add styles with CSS
```

Get the more information, you can follow the link - https://pagely.com/blog/custom-wordpress-landing-page/